# Where are all the plugins for tagging?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.1

After dozens of frustrating attempts to make a tagging system in CakePHP version 2.1, I began to look for a plugin, or some example behavior to get the effect I want, but every one I could find was written in an older version (1.2 or 1.3). I've been scouring the web for about a week now, and have not made any progress with this.

Here's want I want: Question HABTM Tag. In the question add form, one of the fields is a comma-separated list of desired tags. It splits the tags, and already existing tags are merely referenced in the questions_tags table, and becomes a child of the question, while unrecognized tags are created.

Any sort of complete example or plugin that works with CakePHP 2.1 would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/cakedc/tags checkout the 2.0 branch

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this for a long time as well, and this is what I finally ended up doing:

1. Use a regular HABTM relationship, just like you, e.g., Question HABTM Tag
2. Use cake bake to generate the forms/fields and UI.
3. Use the [Chosen jQuery library](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) to make all my HABTM relationships look exactly like the "tagging" feature you see on sites like Facebook and others.

This SO answer may also be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7231879/1203129

In short: I just use the CakePHP HABTM relationships with a jQuery UI to make tagging work.